# NoMethodError: undefined method `create' on model test

Tags: testing, model

i use ruby on rails. i try to write a test. The test is model(unit) test.

```
class Authentication
include Mongoid::Document
field :provider, type: String
field :uid, type: Integer
field :name, type: String

def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  create(uid: auth['uid'], provider: auth['provider']) 
end

def self.find_by_provider_and_uid(provider, uid)
  where(provider: provider, uid: uid).first
end

end
```

this is my model. i write a test a test create_with_omniauth(auth) line. i wrote tthe test like below:

```
auth= OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:identity]
create(uid: auth['uid'], provider: auth['provider'])
```

but i see "**NoMethodError: undefined method `create' on ...**" message. how can i solve this? 
i need to solve and write this test. bwcause my boss wants writing the tests.